# Get next slide title with jQuery (fullpage.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am trying to display the current and next slide section titles. So far, the current slide title is working perfectly but I cannot seem to grab the next slides' title.

You will notice in the afterLoad function I am calling the nextIndex which updates correctly with 1,2,3 and so forth as I scroll through the sections. But I cannot get the actual title.

Thanks in advance

```
//Variables
var deleteLog    = false;           
var currentTitle = jQuery('#current-title')
var nextTitle    = jQuery('#next-title')

// fullPage.js call
jQuery('#fullpage').fullpage({
  verticalCentered  : true,
  navigation        : true,
  navigationPosition: 'right',
  slidesNavigation  : true,
  slidesNavPosition : 'bottom',
  responsiveWidth   : 768,
  scrollBar        : true,
  afterRender  : function(){
  wow.init();   
  },    

  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    var loadedSection = jQuery(this);
    var projectTitle  = jQuery('.section.active .project-title').html();
        if (deleteLog) {
           currentTitle.html('');
         }
         currentTitle.append(projectTitle);
           deleteLog = true;              
         },

  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
   var projectTitle = jQuery('.section.active .project-title').html();
   if (deleteLog) {
    nextTitle.html('');
   }
   nextTitle.append(nextIndex);
     deleteLog = true;
  },
```

My stripped back header HTML where I want to dynamically add the section titles:

```
<p>
    <span id="current-title"></span> 
    <span id="next-title"></span></a>
</p>
```

My stripped back page content HTML: (Note the .active class which of course changes once you scroll down to each section)

```
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section active">
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title One</h1>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Two</h1>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Three</h1>
  </div><!-- .section -->

</div><!-- #fullpage -->
```

Comment: We can not help if you don't show us your HTML...

Comment: Updated to include HTML. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the link to the problem

Comment: Sorry.. I can't see the site URL

Comment: Got my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514643/getting-text-of-next-sibling-with-jquery/44514893#44514893