# Getting text of next sibling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the next Section Project Title `.section .project-title` and echo it out.

My markup has been stripped back for ease of reading here but it is there in structure. I am able to grab the section project title under the `.section.active` div but not sure on how to grab the ***next*** project title?

Please note that the `.active` class changes when the user scrolls down the page to each section, so I also need it to be dynamic.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section active">
        <div>
            <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title One</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- .section -->

    <div class="section">
        <div>
            <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Two</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- .section -->

    <div class="section">
        <div>
            <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Three</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- .section -->
</div>  <!-- #fullpage -->
```

I did try something along these lines with no luck:

```
var indexNext = jQuery('.section.active').parent().siblings().find('project-title').html();
```

Comment: `$('.section.active').next().text().trim()` will do.

Comment: jQuery('.section.active').find('h1').text();

Comment: What if the `active` class is on the last `.section`?

Comment: Sadly that didn't work @tushar

Comment: Sadly that didn't work @Sudharson

Comment: @MohammadUsman I guess it should be blank... Didn't think of that actually...! Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.section.active + .section .project-title').text();
```

I've used a CSS selector to select the `.project-title` element of immediate next sibling. As it is a pure CSS selector so it is more efficient than jQuery's `.next()` method.

You can check the existence of next section if you want. All you need to do is to add a check like this:

```
if($('.section.active + .section').length) {
    $('.section.active + .section .project-title').text();
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
alert($('.section.active + .section .project-title').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section active">
    <div>
        <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title One</h1>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
  <div>
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Two</h1>
  </div>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
  <div>
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Three</h1>
   </div>
</div><!-- .section -->

</div><!-- #fullpage -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the *current active* section:

```
var currentSection = jQuery('.section.active');
```

Get the *next* section:

```
var nextSection = $(currentSection).next();
```

*Find* its *project title*:

```
var projectTitle = $(nextSection).find(".project-title");
```

And print it out:

```
console.log(projectTitle.html());
```

Obviously you could put all in one line:

```
var nextTitle = jQuery('.section.active').next().find(".project-title").html();
```

**See following complete example, please:**

```js
var currentSection = jQuery('.section.active');
var nextSection = $(currentSection).next();
var projectTitle = $(nextSection).find(".project-title");
console.log(projectTitle.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage">

  <div class="section active">
    <div>
        <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title One</h1>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
  <div>
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Two</h1>
  </div>
  </div><!-- .section -->

<div class="section">
  <div>
    <h1 class="project-title post-title">Section Title Three</h1>
   </div>
</div><!-- .section -->

</div><!-- #fullpage -->
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method

```
$('.section.active').next().find('h1').text();
```

Working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gaq23jbL/4/